# Laravel - "simulate"/call a route routine

Tags: php, laravel, routes

In Laravel, I want to have dynamic routes for simple pages functionality.

So say I have couple routes, like `/blog` will call BlogController and so on. And I have routes like this `/page/{slug}` that call PageController.

How can I do it so if route is not found (for example `/my-test-page`), the system would call the controller as if the route was `/page/my-test-page` (so that 404 is only throw if PageController cannot find the page in the database).

I saw I can catch the 404 exceptions, but I don't know how I can *simulate* the route call to PageController from there?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you just register the route `/{slug}` for the `PageController`?

Comment: Because my routes are dynamically loaded from different routes file (for different modules), and I cannot ensure that this route would be registered last. So I dont wan't, say, `/blog` to be caught up to `PageController` instead of the `BlogController`

Comment: "I cannot ensure that this route would be registered last" - why not?

Comment: As the system has many modules and they are registered/enabled dynamically for every instance of the system. I suppose I could hard-code so that particular 'Pages' module registers its routes last, but seems sort of hacky solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
redirect(action(PageController@methodName))
```

Does this solves your problem? Of course you will need to import the redirect() method.

Comment: It does solve it in a way, however, I am looking if there is a possible solution without changing the URL? So for the user it stays as `http://example.com/my-test-page`

Comment: This navigates to controller method, there you can return the view you need. Am I missing something?

Comment: Doesn't `redirect` redirect to the action? So user will end up back on `http://example.com/page/my-test-page`?

Comment: It will take you to the controller, where you can decided whether to return my-test-page or page/my-test-page.